# Can I use jquery while developing a Django project?

Tags: jquery, django, localhost

I try to use jquery for a web project which I'm testing on localhost currently. In my `base.html` I try to use the google service with this link

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js">`

In my rendered site I get valid markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js">
 </script>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").toggle();
  });
 </script>
</head>
```

But the functions don't work. Do I have to [host jquery myself while developing](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jquery/1.8.1)?

Comment: use a browser console to look at errors thrown... would have seen `syntax error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the `ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle();
    });
}); // <-- Close the function
```

Comment: Sh*****t. True. It is Saturday night, I should turn my computer off and put on my dancing shoes. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! Please mark answer as accepted if it helps to solve your problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use jquery in your django project.
The problem with this code is that you forgot to close the ready button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle();
    });
});
```

If you want to use jquery in your django project then I'll suggest you to include jquery in the base template and use that template to create other pages. Also it is advisable to create separate blocks of javascript, css and HTML so that you can choose what files you want to include in particular page, it is much easier that way.